# Loading State or Async Task

Tags: android, loading, task

I have an activity that loads an xml file, but when the app is invoked without reply in 1 or 2 seconds, I wonder if I can put some kind of loading not to appear that the app crashed, thanks.

Comment: If you have things that the user can interact with on the screen, then doing an async task makes more sense (with a ProgressBar widget at top right of the screen for example), but if there is nothing the user can  interact with, then have a load screen makes more sense.

Comment: Ok, and how I do this loading screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb is, if you do **anything**, use `AsyncTask`, otherwise your application will eventually crash on long network delays or large files.

```
private class doSomethingTask extends AsyncTask<SomeData,Integer,SomeData[]> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected SomeData[] doInBackground(SomeData... values) {
        int count = values.length;
        for( int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            publishProgress(count,i+1);

            // do something here
            ....
            //

            if( isCancelled() ) return null;
        }
        return values;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        // show progress bar or something
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        dialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.downloading));
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)  {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        dialog.setMax(values[0]);
        dialog.setProgress(values[1]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(SomeData[] result) {
        // kill progress bar here
        if( this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I would like to invoke the activity, it is open and stay with listview component loading until the data are loaded, as well as the Facebook application, for example.

Comment: that's no problem, `class doSomethingTask` goes inside of your `Activity`, so you may show the list, and there will be a `ProgressBar` over the list, telling your user something is going on.